# Why can I cancel this $\sum_i 2\cos^3(\alpha_i)\sin\alpha_i$ term for pairs 180degrees apart?

Tags: trigonometry, summation

I have the equation,
$$\tag{1} K_{11}\sum_i \cos^4\alpha_i+K_{12}\sum_i 2\cos^3\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i+K_{22}\sum_i\sin^2\alpha_i\cos^2\alpha_i=\sum_i\rho_i\cos^2\alpha_i$$

In the paper it states, "For equal intervals in 180 degree segments the sums of odd powers are zero; therefore,"

$$\tag{2} K_{11}\sum_i \cos^4\alpha_i+K_{22}\sum_i\sin^2\alpha_i\cos^2\alpha_i=\sum_i\rho_i\cos^2\alpha_i$$

The way I interpret what they mean is that, if I sum the values of $\cos^3\alpha_i$ for 0 degree and 180 degree I get a value of 0.  Similarly, if I sum the values of $\cos^3\alpha_i$ for 1 degrees and 181 degree I get a value of 0.  And so on and so forth all the way up to 179 degree and 359 degree, the sum of the values of $\cos^3\alpha_i$ will be 0.  Therefore, we can cancel out the $K_{12}\sum_i 2\cos^3\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i$ term of Eqn(1).  However, if I were to make the same sums with the term $\sum_i 2\cos^3\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i$ I see that I do not get values of zero.  So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{\alpha=x}^{180^\circ+x} \cos(\alpha)=\sum_{\alpha-x=0}^{180^\circ}\cos(\alpha-x)=\sum_{y=0}^{180^\circ}\cos y$$

and this last sum telescopes to $0$ by the identity $\cos(180^\circ-y)=-\cos y$.

The same happens with $\sum \cos^3\alpha\sin\alpha$ since the sign stays the same because of the identity $\sin(180^\circ-y)=\sin y$.

Comment: Can the same be said if the term was instead $\sum_i \sin^3\alpha_i$?

Comment: No, since $\sin(180^\circ-y)=\sin y$ there is no telescoping, so no terms will cancel.

Comment: Interesting, in same paper they write that for $$K_{11}\sum_i\cos^3\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i+K_{12}\sum_i2\cos^2\alpha_i\sin^2\alpha_i+K_{22}\sum_i\cos\alpha_i\sin^3\alpha_i=\sum_i\rho_i\cos\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i$$ can be reduced to $$K_{12}\sum_i2\cos^2\alpha_i\sin^2\alpha_i=\sum_i\rho_i\cos\alpha_i\sin\alpha_i$$

Comment: True, but notice that there is a cosine term

Comment: I see it, but I don't understand why it causes the $\sin^3$ term to sum to zero.

Comment: The sine term does nothing, it is the cosine term which does the trick. $\cos(180^\circ-y)\sin^3(180^\circ-y)=-\cos y\sin^3 y$.